# acl to allowed access application

Tags: server, squid

my application deployed in 192.168.1.20 within port 8080, but if I access using url 192.168.1.20:8080 this error occured :

```
    ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved
```

how to set acl in squid.conf to allowed this url on my network 192.168.1.0/24

Answer (score 0):

try digging [Here](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/)
I had the same problem , it helped me